# How to move this banner to the top of woocommerce shop page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am modifying my woocommerce shop page but cannot get the following "Shop" banner to move above the my account button and below the navigation bar? I am not able to just add the HTML to the header.php file as this banner is page specific. Anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: you must check your header.php, you can find this menu my account and cart link part.

Comment: post your code here